# access my component's child, rebuild it and put it back

Tags: angular

For any `div` or `h1` or whatever within my own component like the following:

```
<app-my-comp>
    <div>original div</div>
</app-my-comp>
```

I would like to transform it to the following on rendering:

```
<div class="..." someAttribute="someValue">
   <div>original div</div>
   <div>a new div generated by my component</div>
   <div>another new div generated by my component</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? I have absolutely no ideas at all so I don't even know how to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-content` to display the original content. Your template will look like this:

```
<div class="some-class" someAttribute="someValue">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div>a new div generated by my component</div>
  <div>another new div generated by my component</div>
</div>
```

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-content-57868654

Comment: That looks promising. I will give it a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That goes way beyond the use case of angular. For angular you'd just provide the "original div" as an `@input`. If you really want to achieve this with any tag you provide in your own custom component, you're going to have to work with `@ViewChild`s and the afterViewInit lifecycle where you use the `Renderer2` to manipulate your DOM manually.

Comment: It is just because the angular powered bootstrap builds the tab this way and I got inspired.